# Cell color in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel with data. I want that as soon as any data in any cell is updated the cell gets colored. As there is no condition (other than that the cell is updated) I am not able to do it using conditional formatting. This could be done through VBA.

Comment: This can be done through VBA.  Please can you show your code for what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Right click sheet tab, and select "view code".

Then enter the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim CellIntersect As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    Set CellIntersect = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)

    If Not CellIntersect Is Nothing Then
        ' Change background color to red
        CellIntersect.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End If
    End Sub
```

If you change any of the cells in the KeyCells range, the color will change to red in this case.
Source: [these MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change) combined with [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/background-colors.html).

Comment: `Target` is already a `Range`. `Range(Target.Address)` means "range on the selected sheet that has the same local address as `Target` has on its sheet", which makes no sense. And, you are coloring the entire Target as opposed to the portion of the Target that overlaps the key cells.

Comment: For the range specified, the code above changes the color of those cells if the contents of the cell are adjusted, which is what the OP asks. I would like to improve it, but your comment does not include enough information for that.

Comment: Yes it does include enough information. Replace `Range(Target.Address)` with `Target`, and use the result of `Application.Intersect` to set the color to.

Comment: OK, thanks, as above. Sometimes there's a glitch in this code in which it colors cells outside of the range, but apart from that, works as expected.

Comment: @citizenkrank. To fix the "glitch" set a range variable to the intersection.  Then if that variable is not Nothing,  colour that variable range.

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion definitely improved it; selecting the complete worksheet and pressing del now does not color the complete sheet anymore. However, the glitch is still there. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: No, it looks fine now. It should not color cells outside of `KeyCells`.